# How to change pre-splash image for iOS?

Tags: unity, ios, xcode, launcher, splash-screen

When I launched my game on my iPad, the screen first displayed a faulty splash image with a black lower half momentarily, before displaying the normal splash image.

No matter what I tried, I couldn't get rid of this faulty 'pre-splash image'. I have tried the following:

1. Entered my Plus package serial number and updated my seat in Unity.
2. Deleted and left all splash images blank in Unity.
3. Checked all the LaunchScreen-XXX.png images in Xcode.
4. Checked the files referenced by Images.xcassets in Xcode.
5. Changed all the above images to a completely black image. Still, the old faulty picture would appear.
6. Cleared all the data and installation files on my iPad.
7. Deleted General > Launch Images Source.

I wonder where Xcode kept the faulty image.

I am using Unity 5.5.1 and Xcode 9.2.

Could someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I restarted the iPad and now it is working! I guess the issue had to do with the memory cache.

Comment: I have the exact same problem with Unity 2019.3 and restating the device seems to not fix the problem for me.